# Manga where the main character can travel to a post-apocalyptic future filled with monsters when he sleeps and has a cultivation technique

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, post-apocalyptic, cultivation

The main character falls asleep in the middle of class and finds himself as a skeleton with only his head normal in a post-apocalypse. There he first fights against limping skeleton with brain and other of its kind then green giant worm. The more he kills monsters the more he gets stronger and more body parts gets restored. After killing a worm he gets new power(something like durable body).

Then he finds an information center where he learns he is thousands of years in the future. He also learns that he will die at a early age and that one of the students who is experimented human with black mutant hand will start rebellion with other experimented humans. He also learns future cultivation technique which kind of looks like aerobics. After which he is killed by a mutant and wakes up. Later he shares cultivation techniques he learned to advance the present time.

It's like *Hoarding in Hell* but with cultivation. It's colorful and any progress he makes in the future dream stays with him in real world when he wakes up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour? Also, what colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I think it's the second answer below. He got the skeleton body with normal head, information center, green worm monster, early death, girl with a black hand who starts a rebellion, and each time he returns to the future he's killed by a territorial monster after some time reading information at the terminal. He wakes up in his bed making progress each time. Only thing he got wrong was thousands of years. It's only 1500 years, but he may have confused it with a similar story "Logging10,000 years into the future." I don't want to steal someone's answer so I just posted comments here and there.

Comment: Oops. The answers switched places. I was talking about Kidnapped Timeline.

Answer (score 3):

The manga is [Kidnapped Timeline](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nll51zn/bangjia-shijian-xian) (绑架时间线).

[Official description](https://m.ac.qq.com/comic/index/id/651791) (via Google Translate):

> Chess can suddenly travel to the future. But I didn't expect that human beings in the future had perished, and there were only bones and monsters everywhere!
> Fengqi strives to find out the cause of human extinction on the timeline, so as to change the future and save the world. But no matter how hard he tries, the result is the end of the world... What's going on?

[image: MC with skeleton arms fighting skeletons]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should add some details about this so the OP can recognise the story.

Comment: This sounds very much like the OP's request. He dozes off in class. Wakes up 1500 years in the future as a skeleton in ripped clothes with a normal head. He kills skeleton zombie by stabbing it's brain inside its broken skull with a femur bone he found on the ground. A window pops into his mind. He's leveled up slightly from killing the zombie. He kills more zombies until he comes to a city. At an information terminal he learns of history, himself, and techniques until he's killed sent back to the present. He repeats and gets stronger. He meets girl with black hand. Tries to change her fate.

Answer (score 1):

Partial match for *[Dreamicide](https://www.topmanhua.com/manhua/dreamcide/)*

[image: Title image for Dreamicide]

> Hazin Nam had always been plagued by nightmares, but one day, he dreams of an apocalyptic world seven years in the future where humans are fighting to survive among demons and zombies. Hazin dismisses the dream as another nightmare until he finds out Yuri Hong, the girl he had seen in his dream, has transferred into his school… With his ability to switch back and forth between his school life and the oncoming apocalypse, will Hazin be able to prevent what causes the world’s destruction?

That said, the zombies don't look like walking skeletons and some of the reviews say the apocalypse is within a handful of years, not a thousand.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the one i am looking for, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the manhua, ***[Logging 10,000 Years into the Future](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/logging-10000-years-into-the-future)***.

> At the beginning of the martial dao, abnormal beasts invaded the world. Humanity’s martials had to retreat in defeat time and time again. Lu Sheng transmigrates to that time, but in his dreams he enters a world 10 000 years later. The foundational body refining method from 10k years in the future is several thousand times more effective than the current one. Then there’s the breathing method, body refining pill formula, and sacred martial law from 10k years later… Despite developing martial arts for 10k years, humanity was annihilated! Their martial arts civilization reached the apex, and yet there was no one left to inherit it. Except Lu Sheng, he’s exactly that last spark of hope!

I had trouble finding it again as well and came across this when looking. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Logging 10,000 Years Into the Future_ matches the OP's description. It'd help other users determine how likely it is to be the story the OP was looking for.