# Manhwa where the main character travels to the future via dreams to a zombie apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, manga, time-travel, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a series I read a while ago about a boy who has the ability to see/go to the future when they sleep or get knocked out.

Some details I remember are:

1. There was a love interest/friend who was a blonde transfer student.
2. The series was full colour.
3. There is *some* magic but only a bit.
4. The main character (MC) can switch back and forth in the timeline and affect the future, the main timelines are his childhood (teen) years and adult time.
5. Love interest is a witch, IIRC.
6. The series is completed.

Site recommended questions:

1. I read it around 2019~ish.
2. It was a manhwa, as mentioned in the title.
3. Basic plot is the MC wakes up in a zombie apocalypse future and teams up with love interest/friend to find the source. He switches back and forth in the timeline to help in solving the mystery.
4. The manhwa was in full colour, and IIRC the title had the word 'dream' in it.

Any help would be appreciated. I loved this series and would like to recommend it to a friend, but I can't remember the title.

Comment: Funnily enough, we've had at least two manga/manhwa questions about someone going into the future in their dreams and finding it infested with zombies...

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266742/manga-where-the-main-character-can-travel-to-a-post-apocalyptic-future-filled-wi/266743#266743

Answer (score 5):

This is likely [Dreamcide](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/41eftkd/dreamcide)

The plot match 100% with what you told. And the manhwa was posted in Tapas.io around 2019.

MC come to apocalypse whenever he slept and he try to find the person who cause this. What he did in his past affect his future and vice versa. I recall he go to gym in present and when he come to future, he get a body of 15 years training. When he is back to present, he retains some of his experience.

In the end he found out he is the one the witch was looking for just like how destiny was made.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, I couldn't find it by searching in google cause all the results are newer series so I really appreciate this 